# Number of solutions to $a-b^2\ge\frac 14, b-c^2\ge\frac 14, c-d^2\ge\frac 14, d-a^2\ge\frac 14$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Find the number of solutions to $$a-b^2\ge\frac 14,b-c^2\ge\frac 14,c-d^2\ge\frac 14,d-a^2\ge\frac 14$$

My attempt:

Adding all 4 equations, $$a+b+c+d-(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)\ge 1$$
$$a(1-a)+b(1-b)+c(1-c)+d(1-d)\ge1$$
Using symmetry, $$a(1-a)\ge\dfrac 14$$$$b(1-b)\ge\dfrac 14$$$$c(1-c)\ge\dfrac 14$$$$d(1-d)\ge\dfrac 14$$

Considering $a(1-a)\ge\dfrac 14$,

$$4a-4a^2\ge 1\Rightarrow 4a^2-4a+1\le 0\Rightarrow (2a-1)^2\le0$$

Thus the only value of $A$ satisfying the inequality is $a=\frac 1 2$
Similarly the only values for $b$, $c$ and $d$ are all $\frac 12$

Thus the number of solutions to the system of inequalities is 1.

$$$$While this matches the answer given, I'm not sure if my reasoning is sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add all these  as $$4a-4b^2+4b-4c^2+4c-4d^2+4d-4a^2\geq 1+1+1+1$$
$$\implies (4a^2-4a+1)+(4b^2-4b+1)+(4c^2-4c+1)+(4d^2-4d+1)\leq 0$$

$$\implies (2a-1)^2+(2b-1)^2+(2c-1)^2+(2d-1)^2\leq 0.$$

We have, $$(2a-1)^2+(2b-1)^2+(2c-1)^2+(2d-1)^2=0$$

Thus, $$a=b=c=d=\frac{1}{2}$$